# Iterative update of tensor slice with tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I'm trying to find a way to update a slice of tensorflow variable iteratively. An example is the computation of all fibonacci numbers up to `N`. I want to end up with an tensor of size `N` such that `F[0] = 0, F[1]=1` and `F[n] = F[n-1] + F[n-2]`.

Answer (score 1):

Below is one way to implement the Fibonacci Sequence in TensorFlow. Following code will print sequence as 2x1 2D tensor Variable. 
Hope this help!!

`import tensorflow as tf`

`with tf.Graph().as_default() as g:`

```
fib_matrix = tf.constant([[0.0, 1.0],
                          [1.0, 1.0]])

fib_sequence = tf.Variable([[0.0], [1.0]])

# Multiply fib_matrix and fib_sequence.
next_fib = tf.matmul(fib_matrix, fib_sequence)

# Assign result back to fig_sequence.
assign_op = tf.assign(fib_sequence, next_fib)

init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    for step in range(10):
        sess.run(assign_op)
        print(sess.run(fib_sequence))
```